# azure mobile app service from scratch

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm having a play with the Azure Mobile app service tutorial ToDoItems and I was wondering if there is any documentation available, which walks through how to set up the service from scratch (i.e. without the ToDoItems example embedded in there).

I run in to problems when I try to extend this example and wanted to understand the underlying mechanics better by setting it up from scratch.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the 30 Days of Zumo on my blog: https://shellmonger.com